# Excel counter for when a Cell with streaming data increases?

Tags: excel, vba, counter

I have a single cell that streams live data.  I'm trying to add a counter to another cell, such that each time the single streaming data cell changes, the counter increases.  (The data coming in is only increasing, so each time it increases, the counter should increase).

Any way to do this w/o a VBA macro?  Otherwise VBA code will help.  thanks

Comment: How are you streaming live data without VBA?

Comment: DDE link of live stock market data.  So the cell has a function like... =XYZ(AAPL, Last Price) and shows the current price

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your sheet under Microsoft Excel Objects. Set the first cell to be the one that's changing, and the second cell to where you want the counter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'First cell
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        'Second cell
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: For if C1 equals D1 on change. If it doesn't equal it, the counter doesn't go up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, also lets say if I have a cell C1 and D1, and for each change event I want to set a counter to compare if C1=D1 at each update/change, what would that look like?

Comment: I've edited my answer for what I think you're looking for. If C1 changes and it equals the value in D1, the counter would go up. Otherwise, nothing happens and the counter stays the same.

Comment: I entered the first block of code as a macro under the applicable sheet, and the output cells are Z1 & Z2, but Im not seeing a count output in Z2.  I changed "Sheet1" to the sheet name, do I need to change "Activeworkbook" to my file name?  any other edits Im not seeing?

Comment: Cant get it to work as is, but If I put the iteration for the count in a separate macro that I call, it works once, showing a "1" on the first change, then stops working

Comment: No you can leave ActiveWorkbook as is - You need to have 3 cells referenced: z1 as the cell that's changing, z2 as the cell that it's checking against to see if it matches, and z3 (or whatever else) to place the counter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in the worksheet_Change event.
In this example, the streaming data would be in cell(14,9) and the counter would be in cell(1,1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 14 And Target.Column = 9 Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat you by 6 seconds ;)

Comment: This only works if I input a change myself , then click enter.  What if the cell (1,1) is a reference to a different cell, Say A1 = Indirect("B7").  The code doesn't work in this case.  For my spreadsheet, A1 is a function.